# Error printing out fields of geolocation object

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class RoadTrip
{
    ArrayList<GeoLocation> roadTrip = new ArrayList<GeoLocation>();

    double cheat = 0;

    // Create a GeoLocation and add it to the road trip
    public void addStop(String name, double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        GeoLocation loc = new GeoLocation(name + " ", latitude, longitude);
        roadTrip.add(loc);
    }

    // Get the total number of stops in the trip
    public int getNumberOfStops()
    {
        return roadTrip.size();
    }

    // Get the total miles of the trip
    public double getTripLength()
    {
        double totalDistance = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < roadTrip.size(); i++ )
        {
            GeoLocation here = roadTrip.get(i);
            GeoLocation prev = roadTrip.get(i-1);
            totalDistance = totalDistance + here.distanceFrom(prev);
        }
        return totalDistance;
    }

    // Return a formatted toString of the trip
    public String toString()
    {
        int i = 0;
        String retVal="";
        for( Object test: roadTrip)
        {

            retVal = retVal + ( i + 1 ) + ". " + test + "\n";
            i++;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

When I return retVal, it returns the values

1. Powder Springs(-110.97168, -110.97168)
2. Argonne(-149.00134, -149.00134)
3. Zeba(-84.74096, -84.74096)
4. Hyampom(-53.2522, -53.2522)
5. North Fairfield(47.05816, 47.05816)

When it should return

1. Powder Springs (70.47312, -110.97168)
2. Argonne (-12.26804, -149.00134)
3. Zeba (-3.89922, -84.74096)
4. Hyampom (84.57072, -53.2522)
5. North Fairfield (73.14154, 47.05816)

The problem is that the latitude value is for some reason equal to the longitude value.

EDIT: Forgot I was messing with the code and removed the latitude part, put it back in; still gives the same result

Comment: Why does your `addStop` method accept a `latitude` parameter and then do nothing with it? Presumably it should be passing it into the `GeoLocation` constructor...?

Comment: You’re not passing latitude into your GeoLocation constructor.

Comment: `GeoLocation loc = new GeoLocation(name + " ", longitude);` Here you are constructing `loc` object where you are passing only two parameters the `name` which is a `String` and the `longitude` which is `double`. What about `latitude` double value which you passed in `addStop` method?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change my code back when I was messing around with it, fixed now.

Comment: please share code for GeoLocation class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. A person working on it with me changed some code in the geolocation and didn't inform me.